# How can I list all Public IP using Standard Sku using powershell or Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface

Ive had an email from Microsoft as below

Action required: Upgrade from Basic to Standard SKU public IP addresses in Azure by 30 September 2025

Rather than look through them one by one does anybody know how I can output a list of Public IPS which have BASIC SKU to excel or other format?

Answer (score 2):

ok worked it out myself, best way to use graph explorer in Azure portal , select Public IP from the list on the left and type the below in the query editor

resources
| where type == "microsoft.network/publicipaddresses"

Comment: If you want only those with Basic SKU you could add that to the query as well:
`resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses'
| where sku.name =~ 'Basic'`